# Remove Tables & Figures from Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, caption

I do not want tables and figures in the table of contents. However, despite multiple attempts over the last week, I have not been able to do it. I am frustrated. Please Help me.[image]

Comment: Not much to go here, we don't even know the details of how your document and ToC are setup. That said, maybe make sure the styles used in your tables and figures don't show up in the ToC?

Comment: A sample document would help. This article shows how to "clean" it of private info and post. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: A Table of Contents will not normally pick up figures and tables, although it can be so configured. Instructions for doing that are on my page about complex documents. Search the page for "includes both headings and figures." http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm -- That yours is doing this tells me that either you have somehow used the heading styles to label your tables and figures or that you have defined your TOC field to include the Caption style. See also Suzanne Barnhill's http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm

Comment: Thank you for reply. Captions are also visible in Document Map. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

### Stop using your Heading Styles for your Captions

Even without a sample your response about them showing up in the Navigation Pane is enough for a diagnosis.

Use the **Caption feature** to caption your Tables and Figures (or equations or pictures).
It is on the References Tab in the recent Windows and Mac versions of Word.
Usually, you will want to create the Caption by selecting the figure or table and then click to add a Caption. This is [my writing on adding a caption](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Caption).

Anything that you type or add in one of the first three built-in Heading Styles will show up in the Navigation Pane and, by default, in a Table of Contents.

See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill' page on [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) for more on the TOC. For times when these styles do *not* show up in the Navigation Pane or TOC see [my Article on the Microsoft site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/headings-that-do-not-show-up-in-the-navigation/1d3bdc6d-218b-4b90-8e58-f1e0530f75bd) about that.